# SQL Server "CREATE PROCEDURE" not executing when procedure contains a join to a non-existent SEQUENCE?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sequence

Does anyone know why the following `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement does not work (it says "Commands completed successfully", but the procedure is not being created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TV TABLE (lKey int null)

    UPDATE @TV 
    SET lKey = 0 --a.lKey
    FROM @TV
    CROSS JOIN 
        -- Joining to select from non-existant sequence.
        (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR TestSeqDoesntExist AS lKey) a
END
GO
```

It appears to be something to do with the sequence not existing in the database - substituting an existing sequence object causes the procedure to be created as expected.

I would have expected the procedure to be created, but to fail on executing with an error about the sequence not existing.

I'm using SSMS v17.9 connecting to a SQL Server 2017 database (v14.0.1000.169).

Comment: My local SQL Server 2017 installation accepts this procedure without complaint and creates it as well. Check for more basic problems in your script, like not operating on the correct database, and check if there are any DDL triggers on your database/server that could silently trip up creating these objects. If necessary test with a clean LocalDB instance to exclude such problems.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7fee7ee3d29a5c664eeb76eda9652f6) this problem. My guess is you're checking the wrong database, or creating it in the wrong database.

Comment: On a different note, what is the the "point" of the above SP? `@TV` is declared prior to the `UPDATE` statement, and has no rows inserted into it; so the `UPDATE` would achieve nothing. Also, the `CROSS JOIN` to the `SEQUENCE` seems meaningless, as there's no rows to `UPDATE` and they're all set to the hard coded value `0`. Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.com)

Comment: @Larnu - the SP I posted is a minimal test case, the original procedure was doing an inner join and assigning the next value to the lKey field, along with populating the table prior to updating it.  However none of this was necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: *"However none of this was necessary to reproduce the issue."* But we can't reproduce the issue, @DavidClaughton .

Comment: @Larnu - looks like this was a bug fixed in the latest CU for SQL Server, which explains why works on dbfiddle.

Comment: That's a point, @DavidClaughton . I just noticed, you say you're using SQL Server 2016, however, SQL Server V14.0.1000.169 is the **RTM** version of SQL Server 2017. Why haven't you patch in over 2 years...?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue has been fixed by Cumulative Update 19 for SQL Server 2017 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4535007/cumulative-update-19-for-sql-server-2017

Although it is not completely obvious to me which of the documented fixes relate (if any), I updated my local Developer installation and the procedure is now created as expected.

Thanks to @Larnu and @[Jeroen Mostert] for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This does however, ask the question, why haven't you patched in over 2 years? The version you are using has known security flaws.

Comment: @Larnu - good question.  Security updates etc are not my responsibility as I'm not the DBA for these servers.  Fair point relating to my local install however.

Comment: I would strongly urge you highlight that the SQL Server isn't being patched then. If you (the company) aren't patching SQL Server, I dread to think what else you aren't.